# On Linux using Python 3.8 PyGObject has Segmentation Fault with Gtk.FileChooserDialog using VS Code but works outside

Tags: python, linux, visual-studio-code, gtk3, pygobject

Under Visual Studio Code, any code that uses FileChooserDialog errors with:

```
dialog = Gtk.FileChooserDialog(Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

but using bash/idle it works.

Example code:

```py
    dialog = Gtk.FileChooserDialog(
        "Please choose a file",
        self,
        Gtk.FileChooserAction.OPEN,
        (
            Gtk.STOCK_CANCEL,
            Gtk.ResponseType.CANCEL,
            Gtk.STOCK_OPEN,
            Gtk.ResponseType.OK,
        ),
    )
```

Comment: Firstly, you're not asking a question, which is bad for Stack Overflow. Please start with the [tour] and read [ask] for introduction. Secondly, what you should do is write a bug ticket or, rather, first search whether there is one already. Prepare a [mcve] though, it's useful for debugging and required for good bug reports and often as well for questions here.